# Dataframe distinct count takes longer on partitioned than on non-partitioned columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `A,B,C,D` saved as parquet files partitioned on columns `A,B,C`, in that order.
I have the following dataframes:

```
dfb = df.where(F.col("b")=="b1")
dfab = df.where(F.col("a")=="a1").where(F.col("B")=="B1")
```

- I run `dfb.select("C").distinct().count()` and it takes 1-2 minutes.
- I run `dfab.select("C").distinct().count()` and it takes over an hour.

This makes no sense to me as the first partition is over `a`. What could be the cause for such behavior?

EDIT with spark explain:

Filter only on `B` I get short explain which runs fast

```
(events
 .where(F.col("B") == "B1")
 .select('D')
 .distinct()
 .explain()
 )

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(D#4970, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#1393]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
         +- Project [D#4970]
            +- FileScan parquet [D#4970,A#4984,B#4985,C#4986] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path/to/parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(B#4985), (B#4985 = B1)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<D:string>
```

When filter A then B it's a long explain, that runs slow

```
(events
 .where(F.col("A") == "A1")
 .where(F.col("B") == "B1")
 .select('D')
 .distinct()
 .explain()
 )

 == Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(D#4970, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#1507]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
         +- InMemoryTableScan [D#4970]
               +- InMemoryRelation [E#4957L, F#4958, G#4959, H#4960, I#4961, J#4962, K#4963, L#4964, M#4965, N#4966, O#4967, P#4968, Q#4969, D#4970, R#4971, S#4972, T#4973, U#4974, V#4975, W#4976, X#4977, Y#4978, Y#4979, Z#4980, ... 6 more fields], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                        +- FileScan parquet [E#284L,F#285,G#286,H#287,I#288,J#289,K#290,L#291,M#292,N#293,O#294,P#295,Q#296,D#297,R#298,S#299,T#300,U#301,V#302,W#303,X#304,Y#305,Y#306,Z#307,... 6 more fields] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path/to/parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(A#311), isnotnull(B#312), (A#311 = A1), (B..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<E:bigint,F:string,G:string,H:string,meta_a...
```

Weirdly, when reversing the order on the lazy plan, it's again a short explain that run fast:

```
(events
 .where(F.col("B") == "B1")
 .where(F.col("A") == "A1")
 .select('D')
 .distinct()
 .explain()
)

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(D#4970, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#2003]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[D#4970], functions=[])
         +- Project [D#4970]
            +- FileScan parquet [D#4970,A#4984,B#4985,C#4986] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path/to/parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(B#4985), isnotnull(A#4984), (B#4985 = b1, PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<D:string>
```

Comment: Could you please add the execution plans (`explain()`) for both statements? Maybe the difference between the plans will contain a hint

Comment: The difference is indeed in the planning, but what's weirdest is that when count distinct on `df.where(F.col("b")=="b1").where(F.col("a")=="a1")` runs as fast. I though the spark planning should have taken care of that. Will edit my original post.

Comment: It looks like that on the "short" plans only column D is read while the "long" plan reads the whole parquet file.

Comment: Do you have a guess for the reason? It is literally just a change of order in the method calls (which are supposed to be lazily evaluated and planned as a whole)

Comment: no idea so far...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the long-running one had `cache()` method call right after reading the DataFrame (selected all columns) as you can see in the explain method below:

```
            +- InMemoryRelation [E#4957L, F#4958, G#4959, H#4960, I#4961, J#4962, K#4963, L#4964, M#4965, N#4966, O#4967, P#4968,
 Q#4969, D#4970, R#4971, S#4972, T#4973, U#4974, V#4975, W#4976,
 X#4977, Y#4978, Y#4979, Z#4980, ... 6 more fields], StorageLevel(disk,
 memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
```

Therefore, you spent time on reading all the columns (no column pruning) and  caching it:

```
                +- FileScan parquet [E#284L,F#285,G#286,H#287,I#288,J#289,K#290,L#291,M#292,N#293,O#294,P#295,Q#296,D#297,R#298,S#299,T#300,U#301,V#302,W#303,X#304,Y#305,Y#306,Z#307,... 6 more fields] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path/to/parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(A#311), isnotnull(B#312), (A#311 = A1), (B..., PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<E:bigint,F:string,G:string,H:string,meta_a...
```

Comment: This is very why would this appear?